# what pattern can be used here to preview this result?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a method to make an order,

```
public async Task<bool> Order(Request request)
{
    // Each step does different things.
    await Step1(request);
    await Step2(request);
    await Step3(request);
    await Step4(request);
    ...
    await StepN(request);
}

public async Task<bool> Step1(Request request)
{
    var amount1 = await changeSomething1(request);
    await Pay1(amount1);
}

public async Task<bool> Step2(Request request)
{
    var amount2 = await changeSomething2(request);
    await Pay2(amount2);
}

public async Task<bool> StepX(Request request)
{
    var amountX = await changeSomethingX(request);
    await PayX(amountX);
}
```

Now I need to preview the Order without any `PayX(amount)` is called. I don't want to add a boolen parameter to skip it, like the following code, which looks pretty ugly.

```
public async Task<bool> Order(Request request, bool preview = false)
{
    await Step1(request, preview);
    await Step2(request, preview);
    await Step3(request, preview);
    await Step4(request, preview);
    ....
    await StepN(request, preview);
}

public async Task<bool> StepX(Request request, bool preview = false)
{
    var amountX = await changeSomethingX(request);
    if(!preview) await PayX(amountX);
}
```

What pattern can be applied here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you create a class that contains both the request object and your additional parameter? It seems like StepX is doing two distinct things - might it be better to break it into two methods and have the parent Order method decide whether or not to call a PayX method, rather than leaving it in the hands of each Step?

Comment: @Blue thanks. but it looks just hide the issue, as it still need to check the condition in each steps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need some middleware-like pattern (Just like middlewares in Asp.Net for example). That's my proposal:

First create An OrderMiddleware class that encapsulates your 2 methods, Step and Pay. In this case we pass step and pay as delegates to the constructor to achieve maximum flexibility

```
public delegate Task<int> StepDelegate(Request request);
public delegate Task PayDelegate(int amount);

public class OrderMiddleware
{
    // Private fields
    private readonly StepDelegate _step;
    private readonly PayDelegate _pay;



    // Initialization
    public OrderMiddleware(StepDelegate step, PayDelegate pay)
    {
        _step = step;
        _pay = pay;
    }



    // Public
    public async Task Order(Request request, bool preview)
    {
        var amount = await _step.Invoke(request);
        if (!preview)
            await _pay.Invoke(amount);
    }
}
```

Then you need a class to handle a list of OrderMiddlewares that represent your complete pipeline.

```
public class OrderPipeline
{
    // Private fields
    private readonly List<OrderMiddleware> _orderMiddlewares;



    // Initialization
    public OrderPipeline()
    {
        _orderMiddlewares = new()
        {
            new(Step1, Pay1),
            new(Step2, Pay2)
        };
    }


    // Order Handling
    public async Task Order(Request request, bool preview = false)
    {
        foreach(var middleware in _orderMiddlewares)
            await middleware.Order(request, preview);
    }



    // Middlewares
    public async Task Step1(Request request)
    {
        var amount1 = await changeSomething1(request);
        await Pay1(amount1);
    }

    public async Task Step2(Request request)
    {
        var amount2 = await changeSomething2(request);
        await Pay2(amount2);
    }
}
```

In this way you order method can work with a list of middlwares.
Just few notes:

If you need to pass other parameters to every middleware, in addiction to the preview bool, consider to create a OrderConfiguration class that encapsulates all these data, and pass it instead. In that way the signature remains clean and you do not need to do any refactoring

Maybe you want to separate you middleware registration logic from your OrderPipeline class in order to not violate the open-closed principle:

```
public class OrderPipeline
{
    // Private fields
    private readonly List<OrderMiddleware> _orderMiddlewares = new();



    // Order Handling
    public async Task Order(Request request, bool preview = false)
    {
        foreach(var middleware in _orderMiddlewares)
            await middleware.Order(request, preview);
    }

    public void AddMiddleware(OrderMiddleware orderMiddleware)
    {
        _orderMiddlewares.Add(orderMiddleware);
    }
}
```